# Unable to build to Github Pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a Jekyll blog that I am able to build locally with `bundle exec jekyll serve` but am unable to build on Github Pages. I forked a [theme](https://mmistakes.github.io/hpstr-jekyll-theme/), followed the [setup instructions](https://mmistakes.github.io/hpstr-jekyll-theme/theme-setup/) but cannot figure out what the issue is.

The error message does not provide any detailed information:

```
The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:

Page build failed. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-builds/
.

For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:

  https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds
```

I went through each of their suggestions and none seem to apply to my situation.

My account and email are verified and I have built several other Github Pages from it without a problem.

The only plugins I use are:

```
gems:
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-gist
  - jekyll-feed
```

which are all officially supported.

All of the files in the repo are about 9 MB, far below the 1 GB limit.

There is no overriding of the [source](https://help.github.com/articles/generic-jekyll-build-failures/#source-setting) in _config.yml.

I am building from the master branch, so it has nothing to do with a missing /docs folder.

I don't believe I'm using any submodules.

I have tried leaving the URL in _config.yml blank, making it `https://<user_ID>/<repo_name>/`, and making it `https://<user_ID>/` with a baseurl of `<repo_name>/`, none of which have worked.

What can I try to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Any Repository url ?

Comment: Here is my repo: https://github.com/jss367/hpstr-jekyll-theme

Comment: Try to debug locally with only `gem 'github-pages'` in your Gemfile. There is a problem with feed plugin. My advise is to find another, more simple, theme, this one is far from perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your title you have:

```
title:            Julius' Site
```

enclose it with double quotes to correctly process it as a string

```
title:            "Julius' Site"
```

Then fix urls:

```
url: "https://jss367.github.io/"
baseurl: "/hpstr-jekyll-theme"
```

## update

The plugin that generates `feed.xml` expects that the `image` element in front matter posts just specify the image filename, but your repo has more keys in it:

```
image:
  feature: abstract-3.jpg
  credit: dargadgetz
  creditlink: http://www.dargadgetz.com/ios-7-abstract-wallpaper-pack-for-iphone-5-and-ipod-touch-retina/
```

when it should be:

```
image:
  feature: abstract-3.jpg
```

The solution is to fix posts using `image` in the above way, if you want to attach metadata to images use jekyll data files.

Or simple remove:

```
_posts/2011-03-10-sample-post.md
_posts/2012-05-22-readability-post.md
_posts/2013-05-23-readability-feature-post.md
_posts/2013-08-16-code-highlighting-post.md
```

Comment: I made those changes and got the same error. I also tried it with the description in double quotes as well, but still nothing.

Comment: Post the error messages at Settings/Jekyll build failure messages

Comment: If I go to Settings->Github Pages, I see this error:  Your site is having problems building: Page build failed. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-builds/.